Is the normaliser of the Clifford group the Clifford group itself?
The Clifford group is defined as the normaliser of the group of multi-qubit Pauli unitaries.
What is the normaliser of the Clifford group?
Since Paulis are themselves Cliffords, such a unitary in the normaliser maps Paulis to Cliffords and hence is in the third level of the Clifford hierarchy. I think you can probably use some characterisation of the third level (for instance that all these unitaries are semi-Clifford) to show that the only such unitaries that map all Cliffords to Cliffords are Clifford themselves, but is there perhaps a more trivial argument?

TL;DR: Yes, there is a simpler argument: from universality of the third level of the Clifford hierarchy.
Let $\mathcal{C}\subset U(2^n)$ denote the Clifford group, let $N(S)$ denote the normalizer of a set $S$ in $U(2^n)$ and let $\overline{S}$ denote the closure of $S$ in the standard topology. We will prove that $N(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}$.
First, note that if $S$ is a group, then $S\subset N(S)$, so $\mathcal{C}\subset N(\mathcal{C})$. Assume then that $U\in N(\mathcal{C})$ is not a Clifford and let $G$ denote the group generated by $\{U\}\cup\mathcal{C}$. If $A\subset N(S)$ for some sets $A$ and $S$, then $\langle A\rangle\subset N(S)$ where $\langle A\rangle$ denotes the group generated by $A$. Therefore, $G\subset N(\mathcal{C})$. Moreover, conjugation is continuous, so $\overline{N(S)}=N(S)$ for any $S$. Therefore, $\overline{G}\subset N(\mathcal{C})$. Finally, by standard universality results $\overline{G}=U(2^n)$, so $N(\mathcal{C})=U(2^n)$. But this is a contradiction, because there do exist unitaries that send Cliffords to non-Cliffords$^1$.

$^1$ For example, $T$ ejects Hadamard from the Clifford hierarchy.
